# issues trying to run GUI C# tests with Gallio.echo test runner remotely

Tags: c#, user-interface, testing, hudson, gallio

I have a set of C# tests that start up and test a GUI.
I user the Gallio.echo CLI to run these tests.
Running on Windows server 2003
Hudson master is running on Ubuntu
the 2003 box is a hudson slave

I can run my tests with gallio.echo locally on my 2003 machine. However, I have a Hudson job that tries to run these tests and it fails, probably because the GUI under test cannot be launched. Error output from Hudson is below:

```
gallio.echo /rt:Xml 'Install Default Path/bin/Debug/Install Default Path.dll'

Gallio Echo - Version 3.1 build 397
Get the latest version at http://www.gallio.org/

Start time: 11:36 AM
Initializing the runtime and loading plugins.
Verifying test files.
Initializing the test runner.
Running the tests.
[failed] Test Install Default Path/AP158aSuccessfulInstallDefaultPath/PerformInstall
Set Up
White.Core.UIItems.UIActionException: Couldn't find window with title Autopoll in process 2884, after waiting for 5000 ms

   at White.Core.Factory.WindowFactory.<>c__DisplayClass3.<WaitTillFound>b__1() in c:\white\Core\Factory\WindowFactory.cs:line 37
   at Bricks.Core.Clock.Perform(Do do, Matched matched, Expired expired) in C:\bricks\Bricks\Core\Clock.cs:line 44
   at White.Core.Factory.WindowFactory.WaitTillFound(Do find, String message) in c:\white\Core\Factory\WindowFactory.cs:line 38
   at White.Core.Factory.WindowFactory.FindWindowElement(Process process, String title) in c:\white\Core\Factory\WindowFactory.cs:line 44
   at White.Core.Factory.WindowFactory.CreateWindow(String title, Process process, InitializeOption option, WindowSession windowSession) in c:\white\Core\Factory\WindowFactory.cs:line 97
   at White.Core.Application.GetWindow(String title, InitializeOption option) in c:\white\Core\Application.cs:line 125
   at IRD.Autopoll.InstallerTestSuite.InstallDefaultPath.AP158aSuccessfulInstallDefaultPath.SetUp() in C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\workspace\Autopoll\Autopoll\test\AutopollSetup_Test\Install Default Path\AP158aSuccessfulInstallDefaultPath.cs:line 89
```

It appears as though the tests start up but the GUI does not launch due to remote display issues or is hidden and cannot be seen by the tests.

Does anyone run GUI tests on a remote windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you run your Windows slave as a service, check the user that it runs under. It it is the `Local System` account you have to check `Allow service to interact with desktop`.